# Get Azure VM price from Java SDK

Tags: java, azure

I need to know Azure VM price and size in my Java application.

using java sdk I could get a VM size

```
List<VirtualMachine> vms = 
azure.virtualMachines().listByResourceGroup(resourceGroup);
for (VirtualMachine vm : vms)
{
    vm.size(); // returns "Standard_D4_v3"
    vm.osType(); // returns "Linux"
}
```

Now I want to search for VM price.

Using Azure public API

"https://azure.microsoft.com/api/v2/pricing/virtual-machines-base/calculator"

I could search for VM price, but VM naming in calculator differs.

In calculator it will be named as "linux-d4v3-standard".

So, how could I compare VM in Java SDK to VM's in calculator API?

"Standard_D4_v3" and "Linux" to "linux-d4v3-standard"

Is it a way to get VM price from java SDK (I'm talking about abstract VMs that are not created yet, we want to calculate VMs price before VMs creation on our side)

Thank you.

Comment: Any more question? Or if the answer is helpful you can accept it.

Comment: Did you find out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure pricing is dynamic, and it changes frequently. Prices also
>   differ by market and currency. The Azure rate card takes these facts
>   into consideration and predicts the monthly bill for the partner and
>   customers.

Not sure, but you can take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/integration/manage-billing/get-azure-prices#java-sdk). You can obtain the Azure rate card through function IPartner.getRateCards().getAzure in Java SDK.  Maybe it can help you. If you need more help please give me the message.